# Get The Total of all columns after Pivoting Access Query

Tags: sql, .net, ms-access

Below is my access query in which i am uing Pivot to get the desired result. I am getting what i want but now just need to show one additional column in the end i.e. Sum of all the hours. Below is my query and result as well.

Query :

```
TRANSFORM SUM(TIBWRKHRS.WRKD_HRS_CNT)
Select TIBWRKHRS.WRKD_BY_USER_ID From TIBWRKHRS
Where  CREATE_TS between Date()-5 and Date()+1
GROUP BY TIBWRKHRS.WRKD_BY_USER_ID
PIVOT TIBWRKHRS.REPORT_DATE
```

[image: Result]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
TRANSFORM SUM(TIBWRKHRS.WRKD_HRS_CNT)
Select TIBWRKHRS.WRKD_BY_USER_ID From TIBWRKHRS, sum(TIBWRKHRS.WRKD_HRS_CNT) as Total
Where  CREATE_TS between Date()-5 and Date()+1
GROUP BY TIBWRKHRS.WRKD_BY_USER_ID
PIVOT TIBWRKHRS.REPORT_DATE
```

This puts the total before the individual columns - close enough?

Comment: Thanks Don Grorge for your reply. One small change in the above query as it gives syntax error after From clause. My query worked using below updated ones :

TRANSFORM SUM(TIBWRKHRS.WRKD_HRS_CNT)
Select TIBWRKHRS.WRKD_BY_USER_ID , SUM(TIBWRKHRS.WRKD_HRS_CNT) as Total From TIBWRKHRS
Where  CREATE_TS between Date()-5 and Date()+1 And CUR_VERSION_IND='Y'
GROUP BY TIBWRKHRS.WRKD_BY_USER_ID
PIVOT TIBWRKHRS.REPORT_DATE